# Get cyrrency symbol while current culture is another than control's one

Tags: c#, wpf, currency, globalization, cultureinfo

My current culture is `en-US`, but grid's language contains textboxes and is set to another language, say, `fr-FR`. How can I get a currency symbol from the input string of textbox?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know culture/region ISO code you can get corresponding currency symbol

```
  String language = "FR-fr"; // <- France (culture or region ISO code)
  String currecySymbol = new RegionInfo(language).CurrencySymbol; // <- should return Euro currency symbol €
```